# How can I access the value of ul with specific class

Tags: html, jquery

Please check the code below I have ol and ul in the same page and I wanted to assess only ul with class can anyone help me with it

here is code for ol

```
<ol class='testing-class'>
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
</ol>
```

here is code for ul

```
<ul class='testing-class'>
<li>test3</li>
<li>test4</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying with

```
jQuery( ".testing-class ul" ).each(function( index ,obj ) {
            console.log( obj);
        });
```

Both ol and ul are on the same page and I wanted to assess the only ul
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS selector you are looking for is `ul.testing-class`.

```js
jQuery("ul.testing-class").each(function(index,obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```